# Adding up in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning basics of JavaScript as I'm more of a back-end guy.
I've got this bit of code that is returning `NULL` but don't
know why:

```
function sum(...args) {
  let added = 0;
  for (var x = 0; x <= args.length; x++) {
    added += args[x];
  }
  return added;
}
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // 6
```

Comment: Change <= to < .

Comment: it's returning `NaN` and that's because your loop goes up to `length`.

Comment: your loop should stop at `args.length - 1`

Comment: Oh ... gosh ....

Comment: `null` is not `NaN`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the below code, I think its internally getting an array index out of bound exception

```
function sum(...args) {
      let added = 0;
      for (var x = 0; x < args.length; x++) {
        added += args[x];
      }
      return added;
    }
    console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you loop goes up to the length of the array, so at the last iteration, it will try getting the value of args[length], which is undefined (array indices go from 0 to length - 1). This explains why the function returns `NaN`.

To fix this, simply make your function loop till length - 1, and not length.

```js
function sum(...args) {
  let added = 0;
  for (var x = 0; x < args.length; x++) {
    added += args[x];
  }
  return added;
}
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // 6
```